# Spring Security + restrict user based on username

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Does `Spring security` having any implementation to restrict user based on their `username`?

I know this we can do it through filters using some `if` checks, though I am curious to know, does Spring Security having any such kinda of implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

For example, an annotation that only allows the method to be run by user "admin":

```java
@PreAuthorize("authentication.name == 'admin'")
public void doAdminStuff();
```

You can reference a Spring bean with `@`:

```java
@PreAuthorize("@myService.hasPermission(authentication.name)")
public void doSomeStuff();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, Now I having more doubts, Is it possible to have @PreAuthorize("myService.hasPermission(username)")?

Comment: Thanks a lot let me give a try

Comment: after trying this solution I getting `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`. Any idea..?